# How to generate checkbox from given array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have given an array

```
$languages = ["C", "C++", "Java", "C#", "HTML", "CSS", "XML", "PHP", "JavaScript"];
```

and I have to generate checkboxes from them.

But not like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="languages []" value="C"/>C
<input type="checkbox" name="languages []" value="C++"/>C++
....
```

Is there a chance anyone could help me solve this problem, because I am stuck, and I can't figure this out.

I tired something like that, but it turns out it doesn't work properly:

```
<?php
$jezyki = ["C", "C++", "Java", "C#", "HTML", "CSS", "XML", "PHP", "JavaScript"];
foreach($jezyki as $key=>$value){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . 'jezyki[]' . '" />'. $value;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `value=` attribute.

You can make it easier to read and write if you use double quotes and variable interpolation, instead of single quotes and concatenation.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='jezkyki[]' value='$value'>$value";
```